# SwiftUI pop to root view

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swiftui

I'm trying to make sure that if a user returns to the app after a certain amount of time they are taken back to the root view so they have to log on again. I can't find a way using SwiftUI to pop to the root view though. I have this code in the scene delegate:

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    if let exitTime = exitTime {
        let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(exitTime)
        if elapsedTime > sessionTimeout {
            //TODO:- Pop to root view here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)
```

in your `SceneDelegate` and then set your window again to the view.

```
//here your log in view   
let contentView = LogInView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```